# count words in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html

I want a code that can count a word in an array of objects. for example how many times the word "young" appears. It has to work in HTML
I have tried with numbers, which works fine but not with the words.
really hope someone can help me!

```js
function count_five_iter(arr) { 
var res = 0
for (var elem of arr) {
 if (elem === 5)
  res++
}
return res;
}
```

```js
var death_row = [
{first_name: "Christopher Anthony", last_name: "Young", date_of_birth: "1983-
09-24", date_of_offence: "2004-11-21", highest_education_level: 9, execution_da te: "2018-07-17", date_received: "2006-03-31", race: "Black", eye_color: "Brown ", weight: 216, height: "6' 1\"", county: "Bexar", native_county: "Bexar", nati ve_state: "Texas", last_statement: "l want to make sure the Patel family knows I love them like they love me. Make sure the kids in the world know I'm being e xecuted and those kids I've been mentoring keep this fight going. I'm good Ward en."},
{first_name: "Danny Paul", last_name: "Bible", date_of_birth: "1951-08-28", d ate_of_offence: "1979-05-27", highest_education_level: 12, execution_date: "201 8-06-27", date_received: "2003-07-17", race: "White", eye_color: "Blue", weigh t: 194, height: "5' 7\"", county: "Harris", native_county: "Brazoria", native_s tate: "Texas", last_statement: ""},
... ];
```

Comment: When you say an array of objects, the word count should only be in the value and not in the key right? Also, can you mention if the object in the array can have inner objects as well?

Comment: Have you tried to click the "Run code snippet" button you created? They don't show nothing, but an error. We need easily testable scripts to be able to help you.

Comment: any you've got that 'count_five_iter' function which has little to nothing to do with your question... do you need to know if a specific word appears more than 5 times or something like that?  If you know the specific key you need to pivot off of ("last_name" for example... ) it would be a bit easier, otherwise you're going to have to track all of the words in a sentence (most likely separating on the commas)

Comment: only the value, i am not sure about the inner objects I am still new to coding - I want to access object inside array - like how many times "Young" appears, this is just a short version of the variable

Comment: Yes to kyle, i need to know if a specific word appears more than 5 times

Comment: ok, that's doable, but again - is there a specific key (key's being: "first_name", "last_name", "last_statement",...) that you need to check against?  If the record that has "last_name" set to "Young" also has something like "I'm to young to have this happen..." in 'last_statement' , should you count both of them?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to get a flat array of all values of all objects ([`arr.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)), join to a single string, and then match using a regular expression that will find all occurrences of the word.

**Notes:** the current regular expression will find the word even if it's part of another word, "dog" in "hotdog" for example. If you want to count only independent words use `` new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, 'ig') `` instead.

```js
const countWords = (arr, word) => 
  (arr
    .flatMap(Object.values)
    .join(' ')
    .match(new RegExp(word, 'ig')) || []
  ).length;

const death_row = [{"first_name":"Christopher Anthony","last_name":"Young","date_of_birth":"1983-09-24","date_of_offence":"2004-11-21","highest_education_level":9,"execution_date":"2018-07-17","date_received":"2006-03-31","race":"Black","eye_color":"Brown ","weight":216,"height":"6' 1\"","county":"Bexar","native_county":"Bexar","native_state":"Texas","last_statement":"l want to make sure the Patel family knows I love them like they love me. Make sure the kids in the world know I'm being e xecuted and those kids I've been mentoring keep this fight going. I'm good Ward en."},{"first_name":"Danny Paul","last_name":"Bible","date_of_birth":"1951-08-28","date_of_offence":"1979-05-27","highest_education_level":12,"execution_date":"201 8-06-27","date_received":"2003-07-17","race":"White","eye_color":"Blue","weight":194,"height":"5' 7\"","county":"Harris","native_county":"Brazoria","native_state":"Texas","last_statement":""}];

console.log(countWords(death_row, 'young'));
console.log(countWords(death_row, 'Bexar'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrayItems = [
  "jeune",
  "une",
  "un",
  "jeune"
];
 
function myCounter(searchWord){
  return arrayItems.filter(e=>e===searchWord).length;
}

var count = myCounter("jeune");



console.log(`count ::::> ${count}`);
```

You can change the function to fit an object table.

```
 function myCounter(searchWord){
      return YOUR_ARRAY.filter(e=>e.PROPERTY_HERE===searchWord).length;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know the field you need to check against you can do something like this, where you make a simple json map of the unique fields - then keep a count of the how many times they appear.

```js
var death_row = [
{first_name: "Christopher Anthony", last_name: "Young", date_of_birth: "1983-09-24", date_of_offence: "2004-11-21", highest_education_level: 9, execution_date: "2018-07-17", date_received: "2006-03-31", race: "Black", eye_color: "Brown ", weight: 216, height: "6' 1\"", county: "Bexar", native_county: "Bexar", native_state: "Texas", last_statement: "l want to make sure the Patel family knows I love them like they love me. Make sure the kids in the world know I'm being e xecuted and those kids I've been mentoring keep this fight going. I'm good Ward en."},
{first_name: "Danny Paul", last_name: "Bible", date_of_birth: "1951-08-28", date_of_offence: "1979-05-27", highest_education_level: 12, execution_date: "201 8-06-27", date_received: "2003-07-17", race: "White", eye_color: "Blue", weight: 194, height: "5' 7\"", county: "Harris", native_county: "Brazoria", native_state: "Texas", last_statement: ""}];

var uniqueNames = {};
var fieldToCheck = "last_name";

for(var item in death_row){
    var _name = death_row[item][fieldToCheck];
    if(_name){
        _name = _name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'');
        uniqueNames[_name] = uniqueNames[_name] || 0;
        uniqueNames[_name]++
    }
}

console.log(uniqueNames);
```